# Can you reply to every email with a "this mailbox is no longer in service" mail?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email

I was wondering if it is possible, in Exchange server 2010, to disable a mailbox account, lets call it **mailuser** and if anyone sends a E-mail for mainuser@domain.com then it will send a mail back with some sort of standard "This E-mail is no longer in use. Please write to blabla@bla.com instead" mail.

I know I can create an "out-of-office" reply from the users outlook, but it would be so much faster to do it within the exchange server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out Hub Transport Rules, there is a really easy wizard there for configuring this.

Hints:
"Apply rules to messages when a recipient's adress contains 'oldemployer@company.com' send 'This E-mail address is no longer in use. Please contact manager@company.com for further questions." to sender with '5.7.1'.

Edit: Just tested it, works just fine!

Comment: Thanks so much Erik, it really did the trick, just what I was looking for. You saved the day :-)

Comment: FYI, these appear to have been added in Exchange 2007. Here are some MS reference links. [Getting to Know Transport Rules in Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb421708) and [Transport Rules: Exchange 2010 SP1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995961.aspx)

Comment: This will require your email to still exist on the exchange. We solved this by moving it to contact, instead of mailbox.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Which action did you use?