# Using Exchange 2010 send auto-reply when a email comes in to a certain email address

Tags: exchange-2010

When an external email comes in to our Exchange 2010 server and is destined for jobs@domain.com which is an email attached to a distribution group how can I send an automatic reply saying "Thank you for your interest..."? I can't see an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is done via transport rules.

Se my previous answer on the exact same feature:

[Can you reply to every email with a "this mailbox is no longer in service" mail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/145364/exchange-2010-possible-to-close-for-incomming-mails-for-specific-acount-and-repl/145367#145367)

Answer (score 2):

This is very simply done in Outlook Rules. Set the Outlook Rule to

- "Where my name is in the To: or CC: box"
- "have the server reply with a specific message"
- Enter the message, as 'specific message' is hyper linked'
- Do not run if the body contains some key phrase in the body of the auto-reply. This prevents mail-loops.